# Will Microsoft Access Runtime work with SQL Server Express?

Tags: ms-access

I am looking into make a simple drawing management/MRP database for a small company I work at.  It is not clear from the description of Microsoft Access Runtime whether or not it still retains the ability to connect to an external SQL database (Like Microsoft SQL Server Express).  I am thinking of purchasing a copy of Access 2010 and then making a standalone app for accessing the database that I can distribute to other employees.  Everyone does have excel here, so I could probably make forms using that, but it seems like Access would reduce the development time considerably.

Comment: You will need a full version of Access for the development, but users can just have the runtime and still connect to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Access Runtime will work fine with SQL Server.  We use it all the time.  You still need at least 1 license for Access, though, because the Runtime version does not allow development of databases.  Also, troubleshooting an app that's not working properly in Runtime is a pain, because you can't view any of the code or "break" (Ctrl/Alt/Break) an app to see what the code is doing.